# c# unity generics interface and abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an `interface`:

```
public interface IMigrationSchema<T> 
{
    T MapEvent(IOtherEvent sourceEvent);
}
```

implemented by an `abstract` class:

```
public abstract class MigrationSchema<T> : IMigrationSchema<T>
{
    public abstract T MapEvent(IOtherEvent sourceEvent);
}
```

and then the actual implementation of my `MigrationSchema`:

```
public class MigrationSchemaImpl: MigrationSchema<EventAfterMigration>
{
    public MigrationSchemaImpl()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override EventAfterMigrationMapEvent(IOtherEvent actualSourceEvent)
    {
        return new EventAfterMigration(actualSourceEvent);
    }
}
```

knowing that:

```
public class EventAfterMigration : BaseEvent
```

What I'd like to do ideally:

```
var migrationSchema = container.Resolve<IMigrationSchema<BaseEvent>>();
```

and having in my config file:

```
<register type="IMigrationSchema`1[[MyApp.BaseEvent, MyApp]]" mapTo="MigrationSchemaImpl">
```

I know this seems abstract, I've tested out a lot of possibilities but everytime I get the `InvalidCastException`, saying that the

`MigrationSchemaImpl cannot be cast to IMigrationSchema1[BaseEvent]`

I feel like this is perfectly doable but I'm missing something simple. Any help appreciated !

Comment: Have you tried without the `'1` in `IMigrationSchema'1[[MyApp.BaseEvent, MyApp]]`?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship between types does not magically become relationship between generic interfaces/types using this types.
`MigrationSchemaImpl` implements `IMigrationSchema<EventAfterMigration>`, not the `IMigrationSchema<BaseEvent>` - so you can't cast one to another (with or without Unity).

You'll get the same error with simple code:

```
var base = (IMigrationSchema<BaseEvent>)
     (new MigrationSchemaImpl());
```

You may try to use [variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) like `IMigrationSchema<in BaseEvent>` (not sure if it will help in your case).

Comment: You got something wrong, I think it's just a typeo: MigrationSchemaImpl implments MigrationSchema, which implements IMigrationSchema. Problem is, even with unity, it works if I map IMigrationSchema (a non generic version) to MigrationSchemaImpl. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that I'm using generics, and that I got the unity syntax wrong!

Comment: @LaurentH - you are right - should be "`MigrationSchemaImpl` implements `IMigrationSchema<EventAfterMigration>`, not `IMigrationSchema<BaseEvent>` " (fixed). The idea is still the same - unity can't magically cast between incompatible types like `IMigrationSchema<EventAfterMigration>` and `IMigrationSchema<BaseEvent>`.